# 'tuple' object not callable for my css file in Django

Tags: python, django

I just added a css file for my Django-powered page. But I'm getting the error message:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\PythonProjects\testproject\testproject\urls.py" in <module>
  25.     (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': site_media}),

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

On my urls.py file I have included the following lines:

```
    site_media = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ..................
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': site_media}),
)
```

The error message tells me that the error is coming from the last mapping in the `urlpatterns`. I have my `site_media` folder stored in `C:/Python27/PythonProjects/testproject`, and my css file is inside the `site_media` folder. Thanks!

Comment: The traceback can be found at http://dpaste.com/876588/

Comment: Next time post the traceback in question body itself instead of giving external links.

Comment: That error usually means a comma is missing. Paste the whole `urls.py`? It's better to double check.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a comma at the end of the previous line.